# Why does a .WAV file sound exactly the same as its complement?

Tags: audio, wav

So here it is, I've been playing around with some C# coding trying to see how much a .WAV audio file will sound different when I invert more and more bits of each sample, but when I got to the step in which I flipped the bits of the whole file, expecting more noise or even that the original audio will not be heard clearly anymore. But when I tried playing the complement of the original audio (all bits inverted), I was surprised the noise in previous steps (less bits inverted and not all of them yet) even disappeared and the file sounded just like the original audio again.

I would like to know what's the reason behind that.

Comment: This has to do with human sound perception. Our ears are sensitive only to the magnitude of different frequencies, not the phase. Flipping the sign of the WAV file is a 180deg phase change, which is not audible.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is not in fact related to C# at all, but the human perception of sound

> The human ear responds only to the intensity `I` of the sound it receives (more specifically, to the intensity distribution over the different frequencies) and this goes more or less like the square of the amplitude,

`I~A^2`.

> Changing the sign of the waveform changes the sign of `A`, which has no effect on `I`.

This is a direct quote from [a post on physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35691/why-does-inverting-a-song-have-no-influence)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the WAV file values are stored using signed integers.

Look at this page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

If you invert all bits of a signed integer, you have the opposite value.

So you just created a symetrical WaveForm, which is the same sound as the original.

Answer (score 0):

You need to approach this from first principles - consider a sampling frequency of 44KHz, and a one bit sampling resolution; a partial stream of a pure 22KHz sound will read as:

```
010101010101
```

If you invert all of the bits, that becomes:

```
101010101010
```

That stream is still a pure 22KHz tone (albeit with a phase difference)

In the real world, the sound waves are closer in shape to sine waves, but the principle still holds - the opposite of what was recorded will appear to be more less identical to the original. It would be more noticeable if you played the inverted against the original down different stereo channels (There's a Pitchshifter song that does this on [2nd Hand on their www.pitchshifter.com album](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B001KUJPVE/ref=pm_ws_tlw_trk2), and explains it at the same time (arond 2:20->2:30) if you fancy a listen)